# iTextSharp: The process cannot access the file. The filestream seems closed

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7.5, itext

Granted that I'm new to C# and Asp.net.

My Web App create a pdf (iTextSharp) file in a folder and post the results into another web page. 
When anyone back to page and re-create a new pdf (modified) whith the same name you receive the following error:

> The process cannot access the file
>   'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\RAPC\PDF\10-2012_file1.pdf' because it is being
>   used by another process.
>
> > **Description**: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
> >     the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
> >     information about the error and where it originated in the code.
> >
> > > **Exception Details**: System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\RAPC\PDF\10-2012_file1.pdf' because it is being used by another process.

**Source Error:** 
Line 132:

```
FileStream stream =  new FileStream(path + "/" + subdata + "_" + CodCli + "_" + DrR1_2 + "_" + G_S_2 + "_" + Data_2 + ".pdf", FileMode.Create);*
```

My Code:

```
// Filestream and PDF create

            FileStream stream =  new FileStream(path + "/" + subdata + "_" + CodCli + "_" + DrR1_2 + "_" + G_S_2 + "_" + Data_2 + ".pdf", FileMode.Create);

            PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, stream);

            doc.Open();

            // Table

            PdfPTable tableX = new PdfPTable(2);
            PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
            tableX.WidthPercentage = 100;
            tableX.DefaultCell.Border = 0;
            cell.AddElement(image);
            cell.PaddingLeft = 30f;
            cell.Border = 0;
            tableX.AddCell(cell);           

            ...

             doc.Close();
             stream.Close();
```

Screenshot: https://docs.google.com/open?id=0ByUzt8ssZaf7Z2YtVXlnRmo3SGM

Seems that the PDF is locked by w3p IIS Worker Process. After few minutes the file return in a normal condition.

I would like that the pdf file is instantly unlocked so the user can modify and re-save the PDF.

Thank You

Comment: You should rather place your `FileStream` within a `using` block so it is automatically closed and released when you're done with it.

Answer (score 0):

As [Ian Kemp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/70345/ian-kemp) says [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12996310/itextsharp-the-process-cannot-access-the-file-the-filestream-seems-closed/13013749#comment17641298_12996310), it's a good idea to wrap your `FileStream` object in a `using` block.  Like this:

```
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(path + "/" + subdata + "_" + CodCli + "_" + DrR1_2 + "_" + G_S_2 + "_" + Data_2 + ".pdf", FileMode.Create))
{
    // ...the rest of your code
}
```

This will make sure that your object gets disposed of properly, which will, hopefully, release the resource every time, which will keep that error from happening.

Comment: If the `FileStream` is part of a `using` statement, it's [implicitly enclosed in a `try` statement that also includes `finally`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664736(v=vs.71).aspx). So `Dispose()` will automatically be called, unless the `FileStream` is a null reference.